# SDE with absolute value

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Find the unambiguous strong solution of the equation:

$dX_{t} = dt+ |X_{t} - t|^{\frac{1}{2}}dW{t}, X_{0} = 0$.

It is easy to tell that the solution exists but I don't know how to find it.
Any help would be appreciated.

$W_{t}$ is a standard Wiener process

Comment: Set $Y_t=X_t-t$ to get $dY_t=\sqrt{|Y_t|}dW_t$, $Y_0=0$ for a start. Does a standard solution for that exist? Is $Y=0$ the only solution?

Comment: Because $(|y|^{\frac{1}{2}}-|x|^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2} \le |x-y|$ then this equation has only solution $Y_{t}=0$, right?